# Enviar datos JS a PHP con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Compañero estoy intentando enviar datos desde un JS a un PHP que me permite generar un documento PDF, aquí el JS.

```
var IDencuestapdf;
var IDcontratopdf;
var IDuserpdf;

function generarPDF (){
      IDencuestapdf = $('#idencuesta').val();
      IDcontratopdf = $('#idcontrato').val();
      IDuserpdf = $('#idusuario').val();

  dataString = {
    'IDencuestapdf' : IDencuestapdf,
    'IDuserpdf' : IDuserpdf,
    'IDcontratopdf' : IDcontratopdf
  };

  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "PDF.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
              location.href ="PDF.php?pdf=1";
          }
  });
}
```

El problema consiste en que aplico en PHP datos fijos y me llama los datos del PDF acorde a esos datos, pero al intentar poner lo datos conforme son llamados del JS me salen que las variables sin indefinidas, aquí el PHP.

PDF.php

```
<?php  

 session_start();

/* Datos fijos usados para hacer las consultas
  $IDencuesta = 19;
  $IDcontrato = 2;
  $IDuser = 3;
*/    
      $IDencuesta = $_POST['IDencuestapdf'];
      $IDcontrato = $_POST['IDcontratopdf'];
      $IDuser = $_POST['IDuserpdf'];

include ('conexion.php');

etc...
?>
```

Comment: Hola! Los inputs *idencuesta, idcontrato e idusuario* estan definidos en tu template html? que pasa si haces un alert() de ellos o revisas el inspector de elementos >> pestaña red si la llamada se esta ejecutando y con que parametros se envia?

Comment: Antes de acceder a la variables *$_post[id]* tal vez conviene usar el **isset** de php, ver link http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php.

Comment: Hola, si están definidos. Voy a revisar el enlace y reviso. Gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php  

 session_start();

/* Datos fijos usados para hacer las consultas
  $IDencuesta = 19;
  $IDcontrato = 2;
  $IDuser = 3;
*/

// validamos que alla algo en post!
if(isset($_POST)){
// hacemos una conversion a entero si existe la $_POST["dato"];

      $IDencuesta = isset($_POST['IDencuestapdf'])? (int) $_POST['IDencuestapdf'] : die("undefined variable IDencuestapdf");
      $IDcontrato = isset($_POST['IDcontratopdf']) ? (int) $_POST['IDcontratopdf'] : die("undefined variable IDcontratopdf"); 
      $IDuser = isset($_POST['IDuserpdf'])? (int) $_POST['IDuserpdf'] : die("undefined variable IDuserpdf");

//con php 7 :

// hacemos una conversion a entero si existe la $_POST["dato"];

      $IDencuesta = $_POST['IDencuestapdf'] ?? die("undefined variable IDencuestapdf");
      $IDcontrato = $_POST['IDcontratopdf'] ?? die("undefined variable IDcontratopdf"); 
      $IDuser = $_POST['IDuserpdf'] ?? die("undefined variable IDuserpdf");
// forzamos una funcion resiva solo int con
// o solo cambiarlo con un cambio simple de:
$IDencuesta = (int) $IDencuesta;
$IDcontrato = (int) $IDcontrato;
$IDuser = (int) $IDuser;

function tusfuncion(int $IDencuesta,int $IDcontrato, int $IDuser){
 //bla bla bla
}

}else{
   die("no an llegado datos");
}

include ('conexion.php');

etc...
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte lo intentare y les informo.